# Update area outside of CGridView via Ajax

Tags: ajax, yii

I'm working with CGridview and updating the grid after an Ajax call. However before I get into the grid I have a a small title and a count `$model->itemCount` identifying how many records there are. How would I additionally try to update this piece of information along with the grid. Would it be a separate JS call?

Appreciate any help

This is my current code for the grid

```
'click'=>"function(){
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('item-grid', {
        type:'POST',
        url:$(this).attr('href'),
        success:function(message) {
            $('#Ajax-Flash').html(message).fadeIn().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000).fadeOut('slow');
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('item-grid');
        }
    })
    return false;
}",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure is this what yoy want but you can use `beforeAjaxUpdate()` in CgridView as shown below

```
<?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array('id'=>'insurance_grid',
'beforeAjaxUpdate'=>"function(id, data){
//Your code to update the title and count
}",
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
'summaryText' => '', // 1st way
'template' => '{items}{pager}', // 2nd way
'selectableRows' => 2,
'selectionChanged' => "
function(id){

}",
'columns'=>array(array('id'=>'selectedCompanies',
'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',

    array('name'=>'Agency Name',
'type'=>'raw',
'value'=>'$data->agencyname',

),
),

));
?>
```

Comment: I actually thought of using `afterAjaxUpdate`. But I still don't know how to update the separate div with the new `$model->itemCount`

Comment: do you have the value of $model->itemcount in the dataprovider that u are passing to the cgridview ??

Comment: Yes I believe so because I am using the $model as this dataProvider. I'm just not sure how to update an area outside the grid or retrieve the count of the dataprovider.